# ThreeJs 3D object doesn't stays at fix origin while interacting using OrbitControls

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am just starting out exploring `Three.js` for a task where I need to render a 3D object exported from maya, I have manage to load this object by converting `.obj` file to `.js` using provided script.

Now i need to add interactivity, like zoom In and camera rotation around the object, very similar to this example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes)

So going through the docs there is `OrbitControls` and `TrackballControls` which does exactly what i want, but the problem is object doesn't stay at fix origin, it rotates on scrolling, and moves around the plane while zooming in and out.

although it's very basic thing but I am having a hard time to figure that out, I have tried setting various properties for the controls but i am unable to get the expected output. here is my [code](https://gist.github.com/isfahad/a8c88d5dd1b22408aa417aa960329c35).

**EDIT :** **Screen Shot**

[image: Skull movement screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `THREE.Box3()` and its `.setFromObject()` method to move the object to the center of the scene (see `createScene()` function):

```js
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var container;
var camera, scene, controls;
var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;
var mesh, zmesh, geometry;
var meshes = [];
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
  INTERSECTED;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set( 0, 5, 50 );
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  // LIGHTS
  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666);
  scene.add(ambient);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
  directionalLight.position.set(100, 200, -100).normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  // RENDERER
  webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  webglRenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
  webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
  container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);

  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    callbackKey = function(geometry, materials) {
      createScene(geometry, materials, 0, 0, 0, 20, "skull.jpg")
    };
  loader.load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FahadSHK/Skull3d/master/assets/skulld.js", callbackKey);
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, webglRenderer.domElement);
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 1.5;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
  controls.enableZoom = true;
  controls.enablePan = false;
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.3;
  controls.keys = [65, 83, 68];
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  console.log("mouse up called");
  isDragging = false;
});

function createScene(geometry, materials, x, y, z, scale, tmap) {
  zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
  zmesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  zmesh.scale.setScalar(scale);
  zmesh.updateMatrixWorld();

  // Move the object to the center of the scene
  var box3 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(zmesh);
  zmesh.position.sub(box3.getCenter());

  scene.add(zmesh);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  controls.handleResize();
  webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

For reference: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/problem-with-fbxmodel-position/1617/5

Comment: Thnx for this answer, actually the issue is with the object pivot point which is not set properly in Maya 3d software, after changing the pivot position it worked, but this answer is worth.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it to run in a snippet here. (As you can see, I did not modify very much). When I run the snippet, it behaves exactly how I would expect. I do not see any errant rotation or panning.

I *do* see several console warnings which suggest you're using an older version of three.js. Try updating to the latest version, and fix the warnings. If you continue to see problems, please update your post with maybe a video or animation of what you're seeing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Skull 3d</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js">
  </script>

  <!-- <script src="JSONLoader.js"> </script> -->

  <script>
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var container;
    var camera, scene, controls;
    var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;
    var mesh, zmesh, geometry;
    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    var meshes = [];
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
      INTERSECTED;
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var isDragging = false;
    var previousMousePosition = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };

    init();
    animate();
    // update(0, totalGameTime);

    function init() {
      container = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(container);
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);

      camera.position.x = 300;
      camera.position.y = 500;
      camera.position.z = 500;
      // camera.position.set( 100, 200, 100 );
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      // LIGHTS
      var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666);
      scene.add(ambient);
      var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
      directionalLight.position.set(100, 200, -100).normalize();
      scene.add(directionalLight);
      // RENDERER
      webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      webglRenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

      webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

      webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
      container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);
      // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
      //var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

      // TheJim01 - Replacing the loader calls with a BoxGeometry, since we can't access the file.
      //var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
      //callbackKey = function(geometry,materials) {createScene(geometry,materials,  0, 0, 0, 20, "chameleon.jpg")};
      //loader.load("skulld.js", callbackKey);
      createScene(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: "red"
      }), 0, 0, 0, 20, "chameleon.jpg");

      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, webglRenderer.domElement);
      controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
      controls.zoomSpeed = 1.5;
      controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
      controls.noZoom = false;
      controls.noPan = false;
      controls.staticMoving = true;
      controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
      controls.keys = [65, 83, 68];
      window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    }
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
      console.log("mouse up called");
      isDragging = false;
    });

    function createScene(geometry, materials, x, y, z, scale, tmap) {
      // TheJim01 - Creating a standard mesh because we don't have the original model
      zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
      //zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
      //zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.TextureLoader(tmap)}));
      zmesh.position.set(x, y, z);
      zmesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);

      meshes.push(zmesh);
      scene.add(zmesh);
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
      windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
      windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      controls.handleResize();
      webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      controls.update();
      webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    function toRadians(angle) {
      return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    function toDegrees(angle) {
      return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried with the updated script but still same output , would you mind having a look at my repo here https://github.com/FahadSHK/Skull3d